# Button on a Navigation Controller on iOS with Delete actionSheet

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, ipad

iOS :
I have app that open some content and i have added button on a right Navigation bar that can delete message content from saved catch, Now i want to put conformation action that conform with user before deleting message,
I have created UIActionsheet like this:

```
sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"   destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Message" otherButtonTitles:nil];
 // view sheet 
 [sheet showInView:self.view];
 NSLog(@"Button %d", buttonIndex);
```

Now how can i use this value in my deleteContent function?
My delete function is

```
-(void) deleteContent 
{
   if (buttonIndex=0)
     {
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fileName error:&e];
     }
}
```

My question is how can i rearrange this in just one function that can be called in one call and does all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the way to do it. Call a function from the button in your nav bar to present the action sheet. Then implement the UIActionSheetDelegate method actionSheetDidDismissWithButtonIdex to take car of your actual deletion.

EDIT: If you need to pass the identity of the item to delete from the method that causes the action sheet to be presented, just add a parameter to you presentActionSheet method and pass the item.

Comment: Cool. If my answer was helpful, please tuck the check mark next to it :)

Answer (score 0):

People having same issue:

Make a function for button that can call popup like this:

```
-(void)popUp
{

    sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you Sure?"
                                        delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                          destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete Message"
                               otherButtonTitles:nil];
    // Show the sheet
    [sheet showInView:self.view];
    //[sheet release];
    NSLog(@"Button %d", buttonIndex);
}
```

and than create one more function that handles deleting part based on popup action like this:

```
   - (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0) {  //delete it

            //delete from database
            //delete from folder
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fileName error:&e];
            //close
            [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated: YES];
        }else if {
             NSLOG(@"USER said No");
        }

    }
```